# How does the default iOS alarm clock play a song from the music library?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

It seems like most people insist that there is no way to play anything but the maximum 30 second audio file associated with a local notification, if your app is not open. Does anyone know then, how the default alarm clock is able to play any song from the music library?

Comment: Without knowing any specifics of this situation, it's often the case that Apple's apps get special privileges through non-public APIs that aren't available to App Store apps.

Comment: ... It's written by Apple, they can use as many of their own private APIs as they want.

Answer (score 3):

Being an app written by Apple that comes bundled with the OS, it's not subjected to the same restrictions third-party apps are limited by. It's very likely Apple is using a private API.

Answer (score 1):

**Apple's own official applications are not bound by the same restrictions that Apple has imposed on 3rd party applications such as your own**. Therefore, it is highly likely that their own apps are exempted from the rule of max. 30 seconds sound.

```
Apple might have been using their own private API for their applications.
```